# Run-time error '424': Object Required - Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

I have the following code in Outlook to save down attachments if an email is received that meets certain criteria.  The code works, however I receive a Run-time error '424': Object Required anytime I startup Outlook. The debugger takes me to this line: Set objItems = objInbox.Items.  But I'm not sure what the issue is or if its even an issue since the code seems to be working.

In addition, the VBA only works when I have my laptop on and Outlook running.  How can I rewrite this code so that it works whether or not my computer is on and Outlook is running?  These are emails being sent to a group email box, not just my personal email.

```vb
Public WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objTaskRequest As Outlook.TaskRequestItem
End Sub


Sub BBDLPRICEMailMessageRule(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String

dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_")
sSaveFolder = "N:\Applications\APX\Import\BB_DL_Prices"

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "\" & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand: How do you think VBA code can run on a computer that is not switched on?

Comment: `objInbox` is not `Set`.

Comment: @FunThomas - I thought because its a group email box.  And because of Office365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `objInbox` object in the code:

```
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set objInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
   Set objItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub
```